# Can you programmatically detect whether a device is a Google Edition Version?

Tags: android

Currently there are some hardware interactions with physical devices that a phone/tablet interacts with in our application.  We target only specific devices for them.  An example would be a hospital that is dedicated to using specific models that they will be using (based on a contract).

We can get the `Build.MANUFACTURER` and `Build.MODEL`, etc. to identify which particular model is being used; since this will change how the hardware interacts slightly with the device.  This in not our exact case however.  Ours is a little bit more open.  Has anyone seen some sort of a pattern that is being used for differentiating between Google Play Edition versions of a device?

All that I have to compare with is an S4 which tags on a 'G' at the end of the GT-I9505 of the S4 model.  I am unsure if this is truly a pattern or not since I have only one of them available to me and do not have a database to analyze of this info. Perhaps someone has come across this need or has picked up how to differentiate between devices at this level before.

Comment: First of all, devices filter list used in `Google Play` is something Google used internally and it's not available outside of Google. Your best alternative is what you have already discovered. Other than using `Build.MODEL` to get a list of devices that you want to support, you may need to contact the device manufacturer themselves to get the device models you need. I not aware of any list available online to help you.

Comment: @ChuongPham There is a 'hardware info' app on the Play Store that I occasionally use as a way to check on specific hardware for a device.  It also as I had found has a database that you can browse through by paying an extra three bucks.  So I was hoping this would be useful; especially since I had over 3 in credits available.  It helps, but it's not a complete list either and tough to browse through.  It's built basically off of user inputs from using the app.

Comment: They probably got a list together - and their list is far from being complete - from searching online. AFAIK, there's no list embedded in the Android firmware that you can simply look up. If you want, you can search for sites like [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/), or [Samsung Updates](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-I9305), etc. Even then, they don't have the full list of devices and which ones are specified as from Google.